# Runtime analysis for the partitioning of an array with Quicksort

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, quicksort

Im working on a research paper about quicksort for school and thus I have to make a precise runtime analysis on best and worst case for my algorithm but im struggling with the part of my while-statements. I understand why its log(n) since you have so many recursive calls that you have n/2^k = 1 and this equation gives you n = 2^k, k = log2(n) and so on ... well since i did understand the recursive calls this part does not really matter but what matters is my following code:

```
   }

        }
```

I have to specify the "cost" for each statement in dependence of my elements n.
So i added a +1 for every if statement since they are simple statements and now i dont now how to get the cost for the while loops. The outer loop runs until the pointers i and j cross so the outer loop gets execuated at least n/2+1 (+1 for the exit condition) - but i cant find out how often the inner two while loops run. I thought that they would run also n/2 times but this cant work since our teacher taught us that we have to multiply the costs whenever we have nested statements which would result in a (n/2+1)*((n/2)+1)+((n/2)+1)) which is clearly n^2 and not O(n) ...
And yes i have to add a +1 for each abort condition and if statement altough they dont really matter ...
I hope you can help me by telling me whats my mistake that i get a O(n^2) runtime although it has to be O(n)

Side note: I think for the while-loops it doesnt matter if its the best or worst case so dont mind that

Thanks in advance
ChampSilver

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the worst case run time is O(n) is that if you have a careful look at the code, you realize that you visit each array index at most once:
observe that index `i` only increases at size, and index `j` only decrease, therefore you'll go at most once over each index.

For example, if you have an array `a[]` of size 10, then the initial index `i` will be 0, and `j` will be 9. `x` will be (randlomly) somewhere in between, let's say `x=4`.
Then, the outer while loop enters, and the first inner while loop increases index `i` until `a[i] >= a[x]`.
The second inner while loop does the same to index `j`, for the opposite direction.

But the sum of total iterations of both inner loops is at most 10. At which point the next outer while loop check will return false and no second iteration will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with this:

> our teacher taught us that we have to multiply the costs whenever we have nested statements which would result in a (n/2+1)*((n/2)+1)+((n/2)+1)) which is clearly n^2 and not O(n)

This is only true if the looping variables in inner and outer loops are independent of each other.

eg.

```
for i in range(1..10):
    for j in range(1..10):
        do something
```

This is because, for every value of `i`, inner loop iterates for all values of `j`. So, this is O(n^2). Now, lets look the other example:

```
for i in range(1..10):
    for i in range(1..10):
        do something
```

In this case, the outer loop runs only once as when inner loop exits, condition for outer loop also discontinues. So, this is, O(n).

Now, lets look at your `while loops`.

The outer condition is while i is less than j. Inside, we are always incrementing `i` and decreasing `j`. So, in this case, the total number of times `while` statements (all 3) are executed will be the upper bound on `i + j`, which is `2n`. So, complexity is `O(2n)` or, `O(n)`.

EDIT:

I am making this edit to explain what "complexity" means, practically.

It is a way of approximating/calculating, number of iterations that are made in total, all loops and instructions combined, as size of input increases. So, if you really want to know that, just assign a variable, say `a` and add 1 to `a` as the 1st line of every loop. Then print `a` for different input sizes and you will know what `O()` notation means, theoretically vs practically.

Comment: "This is only true if the looping variables in inner and outer loops are independent of each other." Thanks for clearing this up.. that really confused me... About the loops could i say that the outer loop runs n times and the inner ones both n/2 which is 2n then and does it matter if its best or worst case in this case or does the partition always take 2n time ?

Comment: The upper bound on these wile loops in 2n, which means, they won't run more than 2n in any case. There may be cases where they run less than 2n, though this doesn't matter as complexity will still said to be O(n).

Comment: Thanks alot for your efforts but i still dont get why the upper bound is 2n since i, if we have the best case,i will only go 'til n/2 and j also, so it should be n instead of 2n, shouldnt it ?

Comment: See this line: "total number of times while statements (all 3) are executed will be the upper bound on i + j". Its not the total number of times inner while loops run. For that, upper bound is `n`.